# What's popular webpart is empty

Tags: web-analytics

I'm trying to put a *what's popular web part* on my home page of a publishing site. The *Web analytics web part* seems to do exactly what I want.

However, it is empty, *whatever* parameter I try.

**Is there any prerequisites to this webpart?**?

What I've checked :

- The web analytics service application is set up and seems to be correct
- Timers jobs are running and are populating the data
- in the site administration, the different web analytic reports are showing populated with data

Comment: Steve did you checked whether Search is also properly running?

Comment: @C.Marius: the crawls were not properly scheduled. After a full crawl, results started to appear in the web analytic webpart. You may answer to the question, I'll grant you the reward for the answer!

Comment: That said, does it means I can use a search query to retrive the same results? I'll have to apply some visual customization and I bet this will be easier using a custom XSL transformation with search result webpart

Comment: Not really as all the data is stored in database (default WSS_Logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So go checking:

1. Usage and Data Health Data Collection service is running
2. The 3 timer jobs  - *Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Usage Data Import* and *Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing*  and *Web Analytics Trigger Workflows* are configured to run at regular intervals
3. Log Collection Schedule is configured
4. Is Search service properly working (returning results) after a full crawl
5. With the job enabled and that some data in the database has been stored
6. If you tried to customize the Web Analytics reports I've also noticed that the "Claims to Windows Token Service" must be started. I've found somewhere on a blog that also UDF Assemblies via Excel Service Application must show the reference to Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.UI assembly in GAC.

Sorry, but without any other details with regards to what you've tried already, it would be difficult to propose anything else.